# iPhone couldn't receive MDM push messages

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I'm developing a MDM solutioin for my own organization. Created an iOS MDM testing server using python mentioned by [imdmtools](https://github.com/intrepidusgroup/imdmtools), generate push certs according to [softthinker](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning).

Here's the cert details:

- Vendor: has an Enterprise Developer Program, the "MDM CSR" type certificate can be found in Apple developer center, downloaded as "mdm.cer".
- Customer: same as Vendor, I generated in Windows 2008 IIS where my MDM server was hosted. The customer CSR was generated by the method mentioned by support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/xmob-dm-8/xmob-dm-connect-create-p12-apns-iis-tsk.html.

The cert file has been created successfully, could be imported into keychain and exported in p12 format. I converted it into PEM format:

- Locate the certificate in Keychain Access
- Export to a .p12 file
- Convert to .pem

  `openssl pkcs12 -in OrigPushCert.p12 -out PushCert.pem`
- Strip the passphrase

  `openssl rsa -in PushCert.pem -out PushKeyNoPass.pem`
- Open PushCert.pem in a text editor
- Replace the encrypted "RSA Private Key" section with contents of PushKeyNoPass.pem
- Save it out

The .mobileconfig file contains MDM payload:

- With the server cert identify.p12
- Push service: development mode
- Topic: com.apple.mgmt.External.e8154c51-4788-44bc-8c23-a2669####f9c

After all, the device can be enrolled by https properly, the server could receive Device Token, Push Magic, Unlock Token from device. But when server sends MDM push message: `{"mdm" : "PushMagic String>"}`, device doesn't receive it. The IPCU device log displays:

```
Jun 13 16:26:13 unknown MobileSafari[374] <Warning>: webFrameLoader
Jun 13 16:26:16 unknown MobileSafari[374] <Warning>: webFrameLoader
Jun 13 16:26:16 unknown profiled[1394] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Profile “-c-o-m-.-c-i-t-e-c-h-.-m-d-m-.-p-r-o-f-i-l-e” -q-u-e-u-e-d -f-o-r -i-n-s-t-a-l-l-a-t-i-o-n-.
Jun 13 16:26:18 unknown profiled[1394] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Checking for MDM installation...
Jun 13 16:26:18 unknown profiled[1394] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: ...finished checking for MDM installation.
Jun 13 16:26:18 unknown profiled[1394] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Beginning profile installation...
Jun 13 16:26:20 unknown keybagd[1403] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [keybagd] (690.10)
Jun 13 16:26:22 unknown profiled[1394] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Device unlock notification received
Jun 13 16:26:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore:Sending lock change
Jun 13 16:26:22 unknown profiled[1394] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Profile “-c-o-m-.-c-i-t-e-c-h-.-m-d-m-.-p-r-o-f-i-l-e” -i-n-s-t-a-l-l-e-d-.
Jun 13 16:26:22 unknown mc_mobile_tunnel[1409] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: mc_mobile_tunnel starting.
Jun 13 16:26:23 unknown mc_mobile_tunnel[1409] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: mc_mobile_tunnel shutting down.
Jun 13 16:26:23 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd [mdmd] (690.10)
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd starting...
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Looking for managed app states to clean up
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSConnectionServer: 0xd622270>: connection set enabled topics {(
"com.apple.mgmt.External.e8154c51-4788-44bc-8c23-a26695####9c"
)}
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x11dcb0>: Sending filter message for enabled hashes {
<10f79d78 c6984a13 f9fc677a 4556fc35 73249ead> = "com.apple.mgmt.External.e8154c51-4788-44bc-8c23-a26695####9c";
<141b878f 22242638 a132b5ba 96284394 eb258b67> = "com.citech.mdm.pushtest";
} and ignored hashes {}
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd) Check-in of Mach service failed. Already active: com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-dev
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown mdmd[1405] <Warning>: Unable to bootstrap_check_in() to namedDelegatePort 'com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-dev'. APS connections will not persist past process lifetime.
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSConnectionServer: 0xd61b820>: Initializing connection server with environmentName 'development' and connectionPortName '(null)'
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd) Check-in of Mach service failed. Already active: com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-prod
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown mdmd[1405] <Warning>: Unable to bootstrap_check_in() to namedDelegatePort 'com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-prod'. APS connections will not persist past process lifetime.
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSConnectionServer: 0x121fa0>: Initializing connection server with environmentName 'production' and connectionPortName '(null)'
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSConnectionServer: 0xd61b820>: connection set enabled topics {(
"com.apple.mgmt.External.e8154c51-4788-44bc-8c23-a26695####9c"
)}
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Network reachability has changed.
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSConnectionServer: 0xd62a150>: Initializing connection server with environmentName 'development' and connectionPortName '(null)'
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x11dcb0>: Removing connection server <APSConnectionServer: 0xd62a150>
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: Interface manager: WWAN radio power level notification; DCH status changed to active
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: Calculated minimum fire date [2013-06-13 16:29:31 +0800] (54%) with fire date [2013-06-13 16:36:26 +0800], start date [2013-06-13 16:21:24 +0800], minimum early fire proportion 0, power state detection supported: yes, in high power state: yes
Jun 13 16:26:24 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: Calculated minimum fire date [2013-06-13 16:34:23 +0800] (54%) with fire date [2013-06-13 16:42:49 +0800], start date [2013-06-13 16:24:28 +0800], minimum early fire proportion 0, power state detection supported: yes, in high power state: yes
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSConnectionServer: 0xd624a20>: Initializing connection server with environmentName 'development' and connectionPortName '(null)'
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x11dcb0>: Removing connection server <APSConnectionServer: 0xd624a20>
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSConnectionServer: 0xd624a20>: Initializing connection server with environmentName 'development' and connectionPortName '(null)'
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x11dcb0>: Removing connection server <APSConnectionServer: 0xd624a20>
Jun 13 16:26:25 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
Jun 13 16:26:27 unknown mdmd[1405] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: mdmd stopping...
Jun 13 16:26:27 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x11dcb0>: Removing connection server <APSConnectionServer: 0xd61b820>
Jun 13 16:26:27 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: <APSCourier: 0x119eb0>: Removing connection server <APSConnectionServer: 0x121fa0>
Jun 13 16:26:29 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: Canceling system wake for [2013-06-13 16:42:34 +0800]
Jun 13 16:26:29 unknown apsd[95] <Warning>: Resuming push keep alive timer in normal mode with action PCActionMaintainPushKeepAliveInterval
```

Changed .mobileconfig push service to Production mode, still couldn't receive. I use github.com/notnoop/java-apns to simulate MDM push, nothing happened. I don't think push message or .mobileconfig file has mistakes, maybe there's something wrong about the cert file.

If somebody could offer some help or hint, it would be a great kindness. I've spent several days on it... Thanks.

Comment: Does the target device need to be added in the device list of Apple developer center to receive the MDM push message?

Comment: Problem resolved. Re-generated the cert file from the beginning, all set to production mode, it works!